# Show that spaces $X$ and $\tilde X$ are not homeomorphic

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, differential-topology

I am a beginner in algebraic topology. I am solving the following exercise from my book:

Problem:  Consider space $X:=\mathbb{R^2} \setminus \{(0,0)\}$. Define space $\tilde{X}$ with quotient topology $\tilde{X} \to X$ as follows:

$\tilde{X}=\{[\gamma]: \gamma$ is a path in  $X=\mathbb{R^2}\setminus\{(0,0)\}$ starting from a point (fixed)$x_0\in X$ $\}$.

and  $[\gamma]=\{\gamma': \gamma$ is path homotopic to $ \gamma'\} $
, for simply connected open sets $U\subset X$  basis for the topology on $\tilde{X} $ are sets as follows:

$U_{[\gamma]}=\{[\gamma \cdot \eta]: \eta$ is a path in $U$ and $\gamma (1)=\eta (0)\}$

I want to show $X$ and $\tilde{X}$ are not homeomorphic.

My work:

My plan of attack is to find some invariant topological property that holds in one space but does not in other.

Any hint or a reference will be a great help!!

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129108/discussion-on-question-by-bhawana-dey-show-that-spaces-x-and-tilde-x-are-no).

Comment: This is the construction of the simply connected cover of $\mathbb{R}^2 \backslash\{(0,0)\}$.

Comment: Yes, this is the standard construction of the universal covering space, in your case, it is not homeomorphic to $X$ since the latter is not simply connected while the former is.